# Checking if username already exists will not show the correct answer

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a duplicate check with PHP and MySQL and have now tried many different varieties. Nevertheless, my code does not show if the user name already exist. As far as I know this should be the right (of many) formula for a functional duplicate check?

```
  $username = "heihei";
  $checkquery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users 
  WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysqli_error());  
  if (mysqli_num_rows($checkquery)) {
     echo ">0" ; 
  }else {
     echo "0" ; 
 }
```

User table looks like this:

```
ID    USERNAME
1     heihei
2     neinei
```

When defining `$username` as `heihei`, result is `0`.

Result is the same if I define `$username` as `something`.

It will show that the user don't exists already.

**What is the problem here?**

Comment: Do this: `if (mysqli_num_rows($checkquery) > 0)` instead and replace `echo ">0" ;` with `echo "Exists";` -  that's what I use with success.

Comment: the query you're sending here is pretty dangerous. consider selecting only the items you actually need to count (seems like `ID` would be enough), and using statement binding to prevent against SQL injection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP username column when username value exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507123/php-username-column-when-username-value-exists). There's plenty of this type of question on SO.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Sure it is. That I will look over later, but for now I need to figure out my problem.

Comment: @MikeB I think it's pretty weird linking a question without an accepted answer, closed as off-topic, -6 in downwote and claiming it is a duplicate. Is it reliable?

Comment: @kanarifugl Goes to show how duplicated your question is.

Comment: Works for me, but you had an error in the code: you didn't pass the connection to the `mysqli_error()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

Replace

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($checkquery)) {
```

with:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($checkquery) > 0) {
```

and replace `echo ">0" ;` with `echo "Exists";` -  that's what I use with success.

---

Try this also:

```
$results = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

$checkquery = mysqli_query($con,$results) or die(mysqli_error());

  if (mysqli_num_rows($checkquery) > 0) {
```

---

**The way I do it in my script, is this:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("xxx","xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username  = '$username'";

   $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
   if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0)

{

die("Sorry, that username is already taken.");

}
```

Comment: @kanarifugl Give me a minute, I have a feeling where the other problem may be.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need some additional info. Is it a server problem or a bug, maybe?

Comment: @kanarifugl I'll post a different example under my original answer, yet in the meantime, change `SELECT *` to `SELECT username` for now, see if that will work. My query is done that way.

Comment: @kanarifugl Reload my answer.

Comment: @kanarifugl So, any luck?

Comment: My problem is somewhere else, because this code is working very well on my other server. It's weird anyway because it has not happend before. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @kanarifugl Ok and you're welcome. I'm sure you will find the problem on your other server. If you feel that this has answered your question, please mark it as answered to close the question properly, cheers!

Comment: @kanarifugl ...which I do believe has answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use another query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE `username` = '$username'
```

And see the results

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($checkquery))== 0){
    echo "no duplicates";
}
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_`